# How to develop a class module for a keyboard shortcut

Tags: vba, windows, ms-access, ms-office

I have a custom button on a ribbon, and I want to create a keyboard shortcut using a class module. I have managed to start it, but I am not able to take the next step, which would be to perform the action. I give you the code:

`

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents Form As Access.Form
Private mPresionarTecla As Boolean

Public Property Get PresionarTecla() As Boolean
    PresionarTecla = mPresionarTecla
End Property

Public Property Let PresionarTecla(ByVal vNewValue As Boolean)
    mPresionarTecla = vNewValue
End Property

Public Sub InitalizeAutokeys(FName As Form)
    Set Form = FName
    
    mPresionarTecla = True
    If mPresionarTecla = True Then
        FName.OnKeyDown = "[Event Procedure]"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmCustomForm_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If mPresionarTecla = True Then
        rbPegarSinFormato (Screen.ActiveControl)
    End If
End Sub
```

`

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to execute a button on a ribbon. The ribbon button is a procedure created by me, which applies only to formatted text fields, to paste without formatting.

So that you understand me, in the toolbar you have a button, which can be executed by means of the combination of letters control + v. I want to achieve something similar.

Now if I do this through a macro, it's very limited because I can only do a few things, and with VBA I can do a lot more. That is, if I want to add conditions or, most importantly, execute a procedure, not a function, a macro is not worth it. Also, I can select which fields I want to apply it to, that is, since the function I'm using is to copy without formatting, it doesn't make sense for numeric fields to be applied

Comment: Not sure I understand the goal here. The idea of a keyboard shortcut is to press keys on keyboard to invoke an action. You want to click a button on a custom ribbon?

Comment: I have answered you in the post. I want a shortcut keyboard to run a buttom that I have in a ribbon, but I want to do it with a class module.

Comment: Autokeys macro is the only method I can find. Macro can call a VBA function. Function can do whatever a Sub can do.

Comment: Ok, I will do it on that way. Thanks.